# utmip in Universal analytics

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm using universal analytics to track some stats about my NodeJS API and all works fine except for the location part. This is logical because I'm doing the request from the server and not the client, but is there a parameter like `utmip` that was available in the previous version of Google Analytics?

This would make it possible for me to set the client IP and will probably fix the location detection.

Answer (score 0):

In universal analytics the parameter to use is `uip`.